# Can I make python read a pdf without giving the path but by having the file open on the computer instead?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

I am very new to python and it seems that every tutorial mentions the need for a path when opening and reading a pdf in python.

The pdf that I want to read can be located in different folders and have different names and I would like to avoid relying on user input. Instead I was hoping that I could open the pdf in Acrobat Reader on the computer and code python to read the pdf file that is currently open. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to make use of the console arguments that can be accessed via the 'sys' module, the first argument is the path to the **python** executable, and the rest are arguments passed by the user like this:

```
python someScript.py arga argb
```

Then you can access them like this via the argv array:

```
import sys

for arg in sys.argv:
    print(arg)
```

In this example it would print:

```
path/to/someScript.py
arga
argb
```

You could make it so you take the 1st user argument as path like this:

```
python someScript.py some/path/to/some/file.txt
```

And then you can get that path using

```
import sys

path = sys.argv[1]
```

If you dislike the user having to type the path in the terminal when launching the python script, or prefer launching it by double clicking the py file, you can just drag and drop the file you want the path of onto the python file and then it will work just fine.

I do realise that its not exactly what you asked, but finding an open file in some process on the pc is way harder and more unrealistic, if its even possible.

Hence i am proposing this alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but paths are so much easier, lol. checkout [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). After you configure the script which navigates to the window you're looking for you're going to need to take a screenshot and use optical content recognition, checkout [pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/)

Comment: Considering OP mentioned he is rly new to programming, its maybe better to tell him more explicitly he really really should be using paths